# Why can't the Swift compiler figure out the type of an element in a mixed-type array?

Tags: arrays, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Here's my code:

```
let string: String = "hello"
let int: Int = 5
let double: Double = 3.14

let mixedTypeArray = [string, int, double]
let elementOfApparentlyUnknownType = mixedTypeArray[0] // AnyObject
```

I've very explicitly stated the types of each element in the mixed-type array `mixedTypeArray`. However, when grabbing the first element in the array, the compiler doesn't infer the element to be a `String`. Instead, it's of type `AnyObject`.

`mixedTypeArray` is an `NSArray`, since Swift's native `Array` type doesn't allow storing elements of mixed types (unless they're all converted to `AnyObject`, but that would lose type information). But if `NSArray` is cool with storing elements of different types, why is `mixedTypeArray[0]` of type `AnyObject`? Is `NSArray` converting all the elements to `AnyObject` behind the scenes? Is there any way to get the true type of `mixedTypeArray[0]` at compile time? I'd like to avoid individually downcasting each element in `mixedTypeArray` from `AnyObject` to its actual type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift arrays only hold one type.  In pure Swift code, your example wouldn't even compile.  You would get the error:  **error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context**.

You code is compiling because you have `Foundation` imported, either because you explicitly stated `import Foundation`, or because you imported `UIKit` or `Cocoa` each of which imports `Foundation`.

When `Foundation` is imported, mixed arrays are treated as `NSArray` which is essentially the same as `[AnyObject]`. This means anything that is put in that array has to be an instance of a *class*.  Since `String` is a struct, and `Int` and `Double` are primitive types, they are not classes.  The `String` gets promoted to `NSString`, and the `Int` and `Double` get wrapped in `NSNumber`.

You can see this if you print out the `dynamicTypes` of the values:

```
print(mixedTypeArray[0].dynamicType)  // _NSContiguousString
print(mixedTypeArray[1].dynamicType)  // __NSCFNumber.Type
print(mixedTypeArray[2].dynamicType)  // __NSCFNumber.Type
```

`_NSContiguousString` is an internal representation of an `NSString`.  `__NSCFNumber.Type` is an internal representation of `NSNumber`.

But the array itself only holds one type: `AnyObject`.

When you do:

```
let elementOfApparentlyUnknownType = mixedTypeArray[0] // AnyObject
```

then the value has the type `AnyObject` because that is what the array is storing.  Swift does not look to see that the item is really an `NSString` because that is a runtime consideration.  At compile time, Swift is not tracking that you put a `String` in position `0` of that array.  It only knows that that array has a type of `NSString` (also known as `[AnyObject]`).

The types of variables are known at compile time in Swift.  At any time, you can <kbd>Option</kbd>-click on any variable to see its type.  For this reason, the best Swift can do is make your variable `AnyObject` because at compile time it doesn't know the underlying types of the values in your array.

You could have declared your array to be of type `[Any]` and then the `dynamicTypes` of your values would have remained `String`, `Int`, and `Double`.  But then, any array access would have yielded a variable of type `Any`.

Swift will not infer an array to be of type `[Any]`.  It will only give you that if you explicitly ask for it.  As a general design rule, if you find yourself using `Any`, you probably are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, all array elements must have the same type. In this case, all the array elements have type Any (not AnyObject, because you supplied one value of type Int). The first array element is of type Any, not of type String. The second is of type Any, not of type Int. And so on.